# How to execute clipboard copy, window opening, event handler, and setInterval in synchronous fashion?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, promise, async-await

I am trying to do the following actions in order:
1. Create filename
2. Copy that filename to the clipboard
3. Open a window to a specific url
4. Click a specific div on the new window
5. Close the window
6. Now, I can print and simply paste the copied filename and finally print to pdf

I need these actions to happen one after the other. I need to run this logic inside of a loop (or at least execute it 200 times). So I need these steps to happen and THEN move to the next item in the html table that I am traversing.

```
let obj = {};

const copyToClipboard = (text) => {
    const tempElem = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(tempElem);
    tempElem.setAttribute('value', text);
    tempElem.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempElem);
};

const traverse = (i, inObj) => {
    const number = document.getElementById('nid').rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText;
    const status = document.getElementById('nid').rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerText;
    const file = `Item: ${name}`;

    if(inObj[number] == "undefined" || inObj[poName] != status){
        inObj[number] = status;
        copyToClipboard(file);

        let url = 'mysite.com/myroute';
        let a = window.open(url);
        a.focus();
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            a.document.getElementsByClassName('anotherid')[1].click();
            const i = a.document.getElementById('myframe');
            i.contentWindow.focus();
            i.contentWindow.print();
            a.close();
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log('Success!');
        }, 1000);
    } else{
        console.log('Failure!');
    }
};
for(let i = 0; i < tableSize; i++{
    traverse(i, obj);
}
```

Some pieces of my code will execute before the others. For example, the windows will all open at once and then the remaining actions will take place. I need this code to execute completely inside of a loop before the next index iteration.

Comment: Wrap the async operations in Promises and chain them or use async/await with them.

Comment: Everything in your question except `setInterval()` is synchronous because JavaScript runs synchronously. The callback from `setInterval()` will also run synchronously. It's just the timing function of the timer that will run asynchronously.

Comment: Where's your loop?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! I have added my loop and a revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only asynchronous thing I see in your code is `traverse`'s completion. So simply define `traverse` to return a promise. Given the code in `traverse`, this is probably easiest if you do it explicitly:

```
const traverse = (i, inObj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  // <===========================
        const number = document.getElementById('nid').rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText;
        const status = document.getElementById('nid').rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerText;
        const file = `Item: ${name}`;

        if(inObj[number] == "undefined" || inObj[poName] != status){
            inObj[number] = status;
            copyToClipboard(file);

            let url = 'mysite.com/myroute';
            let a = window.open(url);
            a.focus();
            let timer = setInterval(() => {
                a.document.getElementsByClassName('anotherid')[1].click();
                const i = a.document.getElementById('myframe');
                i.contentWindow.focus();
                i.contentWindow.print();
                a.close();
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log('Success!');
                resolve();                     // <===========================
            }, 1000);
            // *** Probably want to do a timeout here in case the window never loads
        } else{
            console.log('Failure!');
            reject();                          // <===========================
        }
    });
};
```

Then:

1. If you can use `async` syntax, write your loop using `await` on the promise returned by `traverse`. Example:

   ```
   // In an `async` function
   try {
       for (let i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
           await traverse(i, obj);
       }
       // Done
   } catch (error) {
       // An error occurred
   }
   ```
2. If not, chain your operations together by calling `then` on the promise returned by `traverse`:

   ```
   let promise = Promise.resolve();
   for (let i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
       promise = promise.then(() => traverse(i, obj));
   }
   promise
   .then(() => {
       // Done
   })
   .catch(error => {
       // An error occurred
   };
   ```

Updating `tra